# Adding nth match to INDEX/MATCH formula

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I'm having some issues adding the ability to return the nth match in a rather complicated INDEX/MATCH formula (Excel 2016), I have an INDEX/MATCH formula that works as needed but when I try to apply the ability to return subsequent matches I get a "#NUM" error. 
Here's the INDEX/MATCH that works:

```
{=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$B:$S"),MATCH(1,(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$O:$O")=$D$4)*(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$R:$R")=$D$5)*(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$S:$S")=$C$6)*(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$E:$E")=$D$7)*(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$M:$M")>=$H$5)*(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$M:$M")<=$I$5)*(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$L:$L")>=$F$8)*(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$L:$L")=$F$9),0),1)}
```

As you can see, it uses INDIRECT for the sheet reference as that is user controlled. Here is the adjusted version I've tried (and adjusted in various ways) but continue to get the "#NUM" error.

```
{=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$B:$B"),SMALL(IF(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$O:$O")=$D$4,IF(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$R:$R")=$D$5,IF(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$S:$S")=$C$6,IF(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$E:$E")=$D$7,IF(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$M:$M")>=$H$5,IF(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$M:$M")<=$I$5,IF(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$L:$L")>=$F$8,IF(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$L:$L")<=$F$8,ROW(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$B:$B"))-ROW(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$D$12&"'!$B:$B"),2))+1)))))))),1))}
```

It references columns "B:S" on whichever sheet is selected and this data will change often and can be over 100K rows. I feel as though the ROW references may be causing the problem but I can't quite get it. Any help/advice would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Why not use an advanced filter.  This is a large array formula and a list of them will cause Excel to slow way down in it calculations, with the fact that you are using indirect, it will recalculate every time Excel recalculates, slowing everything down.  I t may even cause Excel to crash regularly.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner, unfortunately advanced filter wouldn't be easily implemented into the sheet I'm working with so I've been trying to find a different way to display all the results of various user controlled criteria. The index/match formula was the best solution I could see but you're correct it will probably make the sheet unusable due to the calculations. Do you know if there's an easier way (aside from advanced filters) to pull/show the results of a COUNTIF function?

Comment: Nope,  in this specific case I would put the data into an area off screen in a format that can be use as the criteria for an advanced filter, using simple formula. Then, use vba in a Worksheet_Change event to do the actual advanced filter with the output where you want it.  That is probably going to be the quickest and easiest to maintain.  The data would be live and change as the user changed the values in the respective cells.

Comment: Could you not use a defined name range and a countif lookup column?

Comment: The best method would be to move the entirety to Access or Sql and create the front end with queries as the middle layer.  That would be the quickest.

Comment: Thanks again @ScottCraner, the Worksheet_Change idea was one of the first ideas but this will be a shared document online so VBA/Macros aren't an option for me. I agree that both Access and SQL would be better but not an option for the users.

Comment: Sorry @AranDG, I'm not completely sure what you mean? Do you have an example perhaps? I understand creating a defined name range but how would the Countif lookup column work?

Comment: It would be easier if you could provide an example spreadsheet, or some screenshots of what you are trying to accomplish. Basically you would have your column of data in say column A, and a countif formula in column B which is basically totting up the current occurrence as a reference, say by using `=A1&"|"&COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)`. Then you just need to `MATCH` against your criteria (for example in C1) and the occurrence (for example 5) with `=MATCH(C1&"|5",$B:$B,0)`

Comment: Thanks @AranDG, unfortunately due to the size of the data set I don't believe this option will work.

Comment: Then at some point we need to tell the users that it just will not work in Excel, as it was not designed to do what they want with the amount of data required.  Good Luck.  Sorry could not be more help.  You are not going to be able to accomplish this with formulas.

Comment: Dick: Can you post a screenshot showing how the user is controlling this? I'm thinking either the CHOOSE function combined with a lookup table can likely help (and will be lightning fast if using it on Excel Tables) or a PivotTable (using either a bit of VBA or PowerQuery to pull all the source data into one easily-queried staging table). But I want to understand what it is your users are selecting.